# Is std::destroy a no-op for fundamental types?

Tags: c++, destructor

I often write something like this to prevent `std::destroy` from looping through arrays of elements that do not need to be destroyed but I have no idea if it is actually useful in any way.

```
if constexpr (!std::is_fundamental_v<element_type>) {

    std::destroy(container_begin(), container_end());

}
```

Will dropping `if constexpr` statement change anything in the behavior of this code?

Comment: Try it and find out?

Comment: The call has no observable effects.

Comment: `std::destroy()` calls `std::destroy_at()` for each element in the range, which in turn is equivalent to calling `~T()` on each element, where `T` is the element type, and such destructor is a no-op for fundamental types.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So by extension `std::destroy()` should translate to an empty loop in that scenario. I suppose most compilers would reliably optimize this type of loop away in case of arrays but I'm not sure if I should trust them when dealing with custom iterators to custom containers... I think I'll just leave that `if constexpr` there. For that _C++17 look_ if anything.

Comment: @BigTemp `std::is_destructible` or `!std::is_trivially_destructible` might make more sense than `!std::is_fundamental`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, `!std::is_trivially_destructible` is much better, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will dropping if constexpr statement change anything in the behavior of this code?

It will not change the observable behaviour in any way, assuming iteration of the container has no side-effects.

The behaviour of `std::destroy` is to invoke `location->~T()` for each element. `location->~T()` has no effects for trivial types (which includes the fundamental ones).

Whether the optimiser can figure out that looping over the container has no side-effects depends on the capability of the optimiser. If the container is an array, this is probably fairly easy to prove.